# I need to obtain Latitude and Longitude from an Address

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I'm new here. This is my first post, but I've been a reader for years.

I've been working with HTML, CSS, JS, and PHP for many years, but this has stumped me enough where I'm asking for help online. My problem is that I need to get latitude and longitude coordinates for street addresses I pass in to my code (77 Massachusetts Ave, Cambridge, MA 02139, for example).

I've looked around for weeks (or months) and tried several people's suggestions, which are often written in JS or PHP. I have a valid Google API which should work just fine (others on my team have been using it in Android successfully, and it's marked as being able to work on our site). I've found many examples on multiple sites, but none work.

Everything I tried produces nothing. I realize Google's requirement to use an API is new and some of the examples didn't use one, but even when I apply mine, nothing works. I'm looking for a clean, modern example of how to get this function to work.

Here are a few examples I've tried. They produce nothing and I'm not sure if I can do error reporting to figure out why:

```
<?php
function getLatLong($address){
if (!is_string($address))die("All Addresses must be passed as a string");
$_url = sprintf('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s&sensor=true&key=[MY_API_KEY]',rawurlencode($address));
if($_result = file_get_contents($_url)) {
$_result = json_decode($_result);
if($_result !== false || !empty($_result->results)) {
return $_result->results[0]->geometry->location;
}
}
return false;
}
$address = "77 Massachusetts Ave, Cambridge, MA 02139";
print_r(getLatLong($address));

$coordinates = getLatLong($address);

$lat = $coordinates['lat'];
$long = $coordinates['long'];
echo $lat.", ".$long;
echo "--";
?>
```

```
<?php
$address = '77 Massachusetts Ave, Cambridge, MA 02139'; // Address
$apiKey = '[MY_API_KEY]'; // Google maps now requires an API key.
// Get JSON results from this request
$geo = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($address).'&sensor=false&key='.$apiKey);
$geo = json_decode($geo, true); // Convert the JSON to an array

if (isset($geo['status']) && ($geo['status'] == 'OK')) {
  $latitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']; // Latitude
  $longitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']; // Longitude
}
?>
```

```
    <?php
$dlocation = "77 Massachusetts Ave, Cambridge, MA 02139";
     // Get lat and long by address         
        $address = $dlocation; // Google HQ
        $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
        $geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false&key=[MY_API_KEY]');
        $output= json_decode($geocode);
        $latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
echo $latitude;
?>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated! If you have any example code which can do this, I would certainly like to see it.

Thank you very much,
BDP

Comment: `Everything I tried produces nothing`. What results do you get specifically. For example, can you post the actual results because *nothing* would be unusual of Google in particular. What results are they returning? Do a `print_r` on `$output` or just `echo` out `$geocode`. Then post that here to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I recently used google api in my projects to get lat lngs from drop off and pickup addresses.  Here is the code snippet .
Hope it may help anyone

```
// url encode the address
$address = urlencode($address);

// google map geocode api url
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$address}&key=YOUR_API_KEY";

// get the json response
$resp_json = file_get_contents($url);

// decode the json
$resp = json_decode($resp_json, true);

// response status will be 'OK', if able to geocode given address 
if($resp['status']=='OK'){

    // get the important data
    $lati = isset($resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']) ? $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'] : "";
    $longi = isset($resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']) ? $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'] : "";
    $formatted_address = isset($resp['results'][0]['formatted_address']) ? $resp['results'][0]['formatted_address'] : "";

    // verify if data is complete
    if($lati && $longi && $formatted_address){

        // put the data in the array
        $data_arr = array();            

        array_push(
            $data_arr, 
                $lati, 
                $longi, 
                $formatted_address
            );

        return $data_arr;

    }else{
        return false;
    }

}

else{
    echo "<strong>ERROR: {$resp['status']}</strong>";
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Danish, thanks! This was very helpful! I think this will work but I'm getting a error saying REQUEST_DENIED, which probably means that there's something wrong with my API. Is there a sandbox API or test I could use from Google to try the code in the mean time?

Comment: There can be few reason for this ...  one of them can be API_KEY. you can directly hit URL in browser  URL tab with your address and API_KEY. make sure your api key is valid

Answer (score 1):

I used this api to get the latitudes and longitudes of a city entered by the user. Please refer to the documentation for getting proper expected results.

Sign up using an account and you will get your unique key. link: https://account.mapbox.com/auth/signup/

https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/{city}.json?access_token={key}&limit=1`